# Add a custom property to Trello Card

Tags: trello

I'm trying to add a custom property to a Trello card. The purpose is so that my app can add additional data (i.e. 'dollar value' or 'duration') to the Trello card.

I have thought of alternatives, but don't think they best suit the needs.
1 - Card Labels: It works for categories but it's not desirable because it can add chaos to the user's labels they already use. Additionally, labels wouldn't work well for data that isn't categorical.
2 - Add a comment to the card: Yes, it's possible, but it feels hackish and if the user accidentally deletes the comment, it would affect the way my application works.

The big issue for me is that I haven't seen anything that says whether it can or can't be done. There was a mention of something like it in a [blog post from Trello](http://blog.trello.com/trello-common-questions/). Here's the quote directly from it.

> Q: Is there a way to generate story points to use with my Agile team?
>
> A: Kind of.  I guess story points are an estimate of how long something will take to do.  This falls into the idea of a custom property for a card that you’d like to have meaning.  For example, if your Trello board was a Sales Leads board, you might want all your cards to have potential deal size $$$ on them.  Right now we don’t want to cram Trello into any specific use, so something like this would have to be provided by a custom plugin (see the API question).

The post is labelled outdated, but I don't see anything in the API docs or anywhere else that it is still a dream or that feature is available. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Lastly, don't think this will affect this question, but I'm accessing the API with node-trello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purposes i'm using the attachment API (power-up library).
You can store the infos as URL (1024 chars long) and show them to user as you want.
I think that, to store more data, you need to store somewhere else and use the card id or the attachment URL as your access key to that data.